# How to custom/append browser name in the method of testng reports in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to append the browser name in the method of testng. So I can differentiate that for which browser my test case has been failed.

Your help is really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of achieving your requirement. One of them is to,

1. Customize the testng reports
   -Use ReportNG plugin - http://reportng.uncommons.org/
   -Use Listeners and Reporters class of TestNG API
2. Get Browser type information and use it in custom reports
   -Pass a parameter from testng for the browser type
   -Based on the driver used, you can know which browser it is running

Comment: Yes I have the browser information. How could you pass the parameter to TestNG? that was my question.

Comment: Search for - passing parameters from testng.xml